# Textview doesn't display anything if the string is over 18175 characters long

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview that has its text set from a local xml file. Anytime the string is over 18175 characters long, the entire textview is blank. Anything at 18175 or under will display perfectly fine.

This only happens on OS 2.1 and under. I've tried looking around for a similar issue but have not had any luck. Does anyone know if this is a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd assume that for OS 2.1 and below nobody thought of a device that would be able to display that many characters at the same time.

If you have a larger String or buffer, you might display parts of it via the `public final void setText (char[] text, int start, int len)` method.

There are various places where Android provides quite sharp resource limits - another example is the default stack size which is so small that it broke recursive methods for me.